# Need CSS to display hidden table rows. Can't figure out Child Sibling selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have table row with an ON/OFF button at the end of each row.  When clicked, I want a hidden row to appear under the row that was clicked.  The button toggles the words ON and OFF just fine, but I can't seem to target the hidden row.  I thought I could just select the adjacent row with + tr or ~tr.  Here's a simplified version...

```css
input {display:none}
.hiddenrow {display:none}
input+label:before {content:'OFF'}
input:checked+label:before {content:'ON';background:#0F0;padding:0 3px}
input:checked~tr {display:block}
```

```html
<table border=1>

  <tr>
    <td>Some data goes here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input id=box1 type=checkbox><label     for=box1></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=hiddenrow id=row2><td colspan=2>This is a hidden row</td></tr>


  <tr>
    <td>This row also has data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input id=box2 type=checkbox><label for=box2></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=hiddenrow id=row2><td colspan=2>This is another hidden row</td></tr>
  
  
  <tr>
    <td>Even more data goes here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input id=box3 type=checkbox><label for=box3></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=hiddenrow id=row3><td colspan=2>This is the third hidden row</td></tr>
  

</table>
```

The problem above was solved, now the NEXT PART OF THE PROBLEM...
 I have another question,  but I didn't want to throw it all in at once.   Now I need to add a second input on each row.   the first on/off switch will make data viewable in a separate div at the bottom of the page.  The second switch will make the hidden row appear.  We've got the second switch working the way I want.   In this example, I have both switches working, but there's a problem.  I have to create a separate line of css for each row (notice the lines for divbox1 and divbox 2 at the end of the CSS)  If I had 1000 rows, this would not be good.  I'm looking for a way to associate the first on/off swtich in each row with the proper hiddendiv without a separate CSS line for each.  (I hope that makes sense)

```css
.a,.b {float: left;}
.a {width: 260px}
.hiddenrow {clear:left;display: none;}
.e {display: none;}

input {display: none;}
input + label:before {content: 'Off';}
input:checked + label:before {content: 'On';background:#0F0}
input:checked + label + .hiddenrow {display: block;}

#container {border:1px solid red;width:300px;height:200px} 

#divbox1:checked~#container #hiddendiv1 {display:block}
#divbox2:checked~#container #hiddendiv2 {display:block}
```

```html
<div class="a">This is where data for row 1 goes</div>
<input id="divbox1" type="checkbox"><label for="divbox1"></label>
<input id="box1" type="checkbox"><label for="box1"></label>
<div class="hiddenrow">First row Hidden content. Hidden content.</div>
<br>
<div class="a">This is where data for row 2 goes</div>
<input id="divbox2" type="checkbox"><label for="divbox2"></label>
<input id="box2" type="checkbox"><label for="box2"></label>
<div class="hiddenrow">Second row Hidden content. Hidden content.</div>
<br>

<br><br>
<div id="container">
<div class="e" id="hiddendiv1"><br>div 1 is now viewable</div>
<div class="e" id="hiddendiv2"><br>div 2 is now viewable</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `input:checked~tr` doesn't work because `tr` is not a sibling of `input`. You're attempting to move up and back down the DOM with CSS, which you cannot do.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the problem.  If I put the input above the table, that might work, but how would I do it.  I need the label text to change, and the hidden row to appear. when the label is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

`input:checked~tr` doesn't work because `tr` is not a sibling of `input`. You're attempting to move up and back down the DOM with CSS, which you cannot do.

I don't know if using a table is required or not but off the top of my head the only thing I can think of is re-working the markup so you can use next sibling selector `+`.

This is a rough example but something like this might work for you.

```css
.a,
.b {
  float: left;
}
.a {
  width: calc(100% - 45px);
}
.b {
  width: 45px;
}
.c {
  clear: left;
  display: none;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  text-align: center;
}
input + label:before {
  content: 'Off';
}
input:checked+label {
  background: #fc0;
}
input:checked + label:before {
  content: 'On';
}
input:checked + label + .c {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">1) Some content here.</div>
<input id="box1" type="checkbox">
<label class="b" for="box1"></label>
<div class="c">
  Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content.
</div>
<div class="a">2) Some content here.</div>
<input id="box2" type="checkbox">
<label class="b" for="box2"></label>
<div class="c">
  Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content. Hidden content.
</div>
```

Comment: You should post a new question then.

Comment: Its really the same question, I just added another feature to the table.  I posted it up above.

Comment: @CheeseFlavored That's a separate question. It looks like you're trying to program with CSS. You should be using JS to solve these issues. Although my answer may have worked for your initial question, it's functionality and markup is bound to the selectors available to CSS and isn't the greatest idea IMHO. It would be best to separate the concerns and create more semantic and readable markup with a little bit of JS sprinkled. Right now you're attempting to get CSS to provide the behavioral layer which is JS' job in the first place.